# optimal lifted phylogenetic alignment - how to improve time complexity?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, trees, strings, bioinformatics

[optimal lifted alignment](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~rshamir/algmb/98/scribe/html/lec05/node7.html) - is a dynamic programming algorithm. Its input is a tree $T$ with $k$ strings assigned to its leaf nodes (their length is $n$).

The algorithm then assigns strings to the internal nodes s.t. the sum of distance (global alignment [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)) on all the edges would be minimal, under the constraint that the string assigned to each node is one of the strings of its immediate children (hence the name "lifted").

The algorithm first computes distances $D$ between all pairs $O(k^2n^2)$. For each leaf node $v$ assigned $S_v$ we initialize: $d(S, v) = 0 | S = S_v$ and $d(S, v) = \infty | S \neq S_v$.

We then traverse post-order and for each internal node $v$, for each string $S$ assigned to one of its leaf descendants (all strings in its subtree) does $d(v,S) = \sum{\min(D(S,T) + d(w,T))}$ where $w$ are $v$'s immediate children. Overall = $O(k^2n^2 + k^3)$.

I've been told its possible to improve the complexity to $O(k^2n^2 + k^2)$ but I can't see how? Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $d(v, s)$ -- is $s$ the same as $S$?  Also don't you mean "for each string $S$ assigned to one of its *immediate children*"?  (If you chose a string for a node that was *not* one of the strings assigned to its immediate children, this would be an invalid solution, would it not?)

Comment: I don't quite understand your algorithm and its running time analysis, and the link you provided is in somewhat bad shape. Please explain more clearly the problem, the algorithm, and the runtime analysis.

Comment: (Side note: If all strings have length $n$, it suggests you may want Hamming distance, which (unlike, say, Levenshtein distance) can be computed in linear time, shaving a factor of $n$.)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, j_random_hacker - tried to clarify all your (justified) questions in the description. Please revise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a node $x$ with children $x_1,\ldots,x_d$, and denote by $N(v)$ the number of leaves in the subtree $T(v)$ rooted at $v$. We can implement the processing of $x$ as follows:

- Go over $1 \leq i \leq d$:
- - Choose a leaf $f_i \in T(x_i)$ as the label of $x$ and $x_i$.
- - For all $j \neq i$, choose the leaf $f_j \in T(x_j)$ that minimizes $D(f_i,f_j) + d(x_j,f_j)$.
- - Store $d(x,f_i) = \sum_{j \neq i} [D(f_i,f_j) + d(x_j,f_j)]$.

The processing time of $x$ is proportional to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d N(x_i) \times \sum_{j \neq i} N(x_j) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^d N(x_i)\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^d N(x_i)^2 = N(x)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^d N(x_i)^2.
$$
Summing over all nodes $x$ up to the root $r$, we see that the total processing time is proportional to $N(r)^2 = k^2$.

Comment: Wow, that's great! Can you share how did you come up with the intuition to this direction?

Comment: I guessed that the actual running time is $O(k^2)$, I wrote the recurrence relation, and this popped out.